# Easy way to change ProgressBar standard color scheme in Mono for Android?

Tags: android, progress-bar, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am looking for a way to change the tint and background colors of a standard android ProgressBar in Xamarin Studio. Found some tips for how this is done in java like this:

```
myprogress.setBackgroundDrawable(c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress));
```

But I couldn't figure out how to use this in Xamarin. I have also seen the pretty large xml files, making gradient backgrounds. But shouldn't there be an easy way to just change the colors without any gradient?

Answer (score 1):

you should probably go with this.

in res/values add new style by adding

```
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.Process" parent="android:Theme.Light">
<item name ="android:background">#2D2D2D</item>
<item name ="background">#2D2D2D</item>
</style>
```

Now use this style in your ProgressBar.

```
myprogress.setProgressStyle(R.style.Process);
```

you can change color code in backgroud of style..

Comment: I just have Strings.xml file in Resources/values folder. Where do I add this?

Comment: Right click on values -> New -> Others -> Android XML file
give name as "styles.xml" and select "resources" and Finish..

Comment: We seem to be working in different versions of Xamarin Studio.. But thank you for the answer anyways!

Answer (score 0):

To convert the Java to C#, it would look like this:

```
myprogress.SetBackgroundDrawable(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.progress));
```

All you need to do is put the drawable (png, xml, etc) you want to use as the background in your Resources/drawable folder.  If you just want a gradient you should use xml instead of a bitmap.  Create a new xml file in your Resources/drawable folder, here is an example of a blue gradient:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#065b92"
        android:endColor="#1183ce"
        android:type="linear"
        />
</shape>
```